# how to know Changes has done in my form before update

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

After retriving the data from database, When I click the Update button there will raise a messagebox  as "Changes has done.Do u like to proceed" with Yes/No buttons. But i want to raise the message box when I made any changes only. If i didn't make any changes it should not raise.. Please help me how to know the changes in my textboxes and comboxes.
My code for raising is

```
DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("Chanes has done, Do you wish to save changes.?", "Message",MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);
if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
{
// HERE MY UPDATE CODE.
}
```

Comment: And what have you tried? Are you using data binding? Entity Framework? ADO.NET? Do you want to detect real changes (e.g. typing the same value into textbox is not considered an edit)?

Comment: Iam using ADO.Net. Yes. I want to detect the real changes.

Comment: How do you set the initial values for the controls? Are them data-bound to ADO.NET record, or you explicitly extract values from the dataset and set them to your controls?

Comment: Iam extracting the values from Dataset to my controls.

Comment: Than you have no better options than @thersch mentioned. The common approach is to mark *everything* as modified if *anything* had a *chance* to change. Note that even in Notepad if you add a character and than remove it, it's considered an edit an you'll be prompted to save the changes. In your particular case I would add a most generic event-handler to all your controls on `Page_Load` and have that handler set some boolean property indicating that something had changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to store the original values as strings, then compare these to the resulting values.

Alternatively a simpler implementation could just set a boolean `isDirty` flag to true on the text box changed event, and reset to false on a successful update.

Example code to help highlight what's needed included below:

```
if(ValuesHaveChanged())
{
    DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("Data has been changed, do you wish to save changes?", "Save Changes",MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);
    if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
    {
        // HERE MY UPDATE CODE.
        ResetChangeDetection();
    }
}
```

.

```
private bool ValuesHaveChanged()
{
    return this.isDirty;
    /*
    return ! 
    (
        this.savedName.Equals(NameTextbox.Text)
        && this.savedAddress.Equals(AddressTextbox.Text)
    )
    */
}
```

.

```
private void ResetChangeDetection()
{
    this.isDirty = false;
    //this.savedName = NameTextbox.Text;
    //this.savedAddress = AddressTextbox.Text;
}
```

Comment: No worries.  NB: I just changed the reset code to be in its own function; that way you can call it when the form's initialised, when an update occurs, if you put in button to reset the form's values to their original ones, or anywhere else.  It also means you can change between the `isDirty` and the `text_before != text_after` methods more easily.

Answer (score 2):

**Option 1: Compare** old values with new values before showing message.

**Option 2:** Add a member variable ***dirty*** to your form and register to change events of every sub control.
In event handlers: Check if value has been changed. If so set *dirty* to true.

**Option 3:** (My favorite.) **Do not do any check** because it is too hard to maintain these checks. You need to change your checks for every change in your data structure or sub controls.
Just remove "Changes has done" from your message. User knows himself whether he has really changed his data. So just ask "Do you wish to save changes?".

Comment: Option3: In that case it will raise if there doesnot made any changes.

Comment: If it raises an exception and if that exception is identifiable you could catch that exception. You could ignore it or you could show a message like "Data not updated because there were no changes!". - Or you implement option 1 or 2.

Comment: k. Thanq.. Sir i have a doubt.. What will you get if u give me reply.. Helping or any income.

Comment: @Naresh Do you want that I delete my answer?

Comment: NO sir.. I jus asking casually. If u dont mind only.. iam sorry